# In how many ways can $11$ people be seated at a rectangular table with $6$ chairs on either side of the longer edge?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A group of $11$ people went to a party. There were $5$ girls and $6$ boys.  They were seated at a rectangular table with $6$ chairs on either side of the longer edge.

a. What is the total number of ways the group could be seated?

Answer is $11C6 \cdot 6! \cdot 6P5$. I did not understand this at all.

Comment: There are $12$ seats, six on each side of the table (none at the short ends).  We wish to seat $11$ people.  How many people must sit on one side of the table?  How many must sit on the other side?  How many ways can they be arranged?

Comment: I don't know that is why I Have asked @N.F.Taussig

Comment: We can only have one empty seat.  What does this imply about the number of people on each side of the table?

Comment: 6 girls and 5 boys can be seated on both the sides @N.F.Taussig

Comment: There are only six seats on each side.  How many people are one side?  How many are on the other?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be wrong.  The correct answer is $12!$, which can be understood by making $12$ cards, $11$ of which contain the names of the guests and one of which contains the word "empty".  Then arrange the $12$ cards in the $12$ seats.

I believe that the answer you quote was obtained by the following thought process:

1. choose which $6$ of the $11$ people are to sit on the right side of the table;
2. assign the $6$ seats on the right side to those $6$ people;
3. assign seats on the left side to the $5$ remaining people.

What is wrong with this is that it assumes the empty seat will be on the left side.  One must double the answer to account for the possibility that the empty seat is on the right side.  If one does that, the two answers agree.

**Added:** It is possible that you are meant to assume that seating assignments that differ only by $180^\circ$ rotations of the table are equivalent.  Under this assumption, the stated answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem:

You have $11$ people and $12$ seats, so $11$ seats are filled and $1$ is empty. Now, $11$ people can be seated in $11$ seats in $11!$ ways. Now first we choose which seat to leave empty and then we can seat the $11$ people on the remaining seats. So we have $12$ choices for which seat to leave empty. Then we can seat the $11$ people in $11!$ ways. So the total number of ways to seat the $11$ people in $12$ seats is:
$$12 \times 11! = 12!$$
So the correct answer is $12!=479001600$ ways.